# Error in setting up .SSH keys with Windows PowerShell

Tags: git, powershell, ssh, ssh-keys

I've got the GIT BASH shell working correctly with SSH keys, so I know my basic configuration steps are correct, but I prefer the windows powershell (actually I prefer the Mac or Linux terminal, but out of the available options...)

Anyways.

My windows powershell is set up with the PS1 script fount in this blog post
http://markembling.info/2009/09/ssh-agent-in-powershell and from what I can tell, the start up is running correctly

```
Starting SSH agent...
SSH agent PID: 5064
```

But when I try to SSH in or run git commands from powershell, I'm still prompted for a password.  Has anyone seen this before?  I prefer PS to Git Bash but will stick with it in the worst case.

**EDIT** - Answer provided by VonC = Add %HOME% to windows system environment variables

```
To view or change environment variables:

Right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.
Click the Advanced tab.
Click Environment variables.
Click one the following options, under user variables:
    Click New 
         variable name `HOME` (No quotes, or percentage signs) 
         value: C:\Documents and Settings\**your username**
            or: C:\Users\**your username**
```

Restart powershell (or whatever shell you love) and your SSH works by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first element to check is the value of the environment variable `%HOME%`.
It might be naturally set in a bash session, but in a Windows (here PowerShell) session, it is not defined by default.

It is best to defined that variable at the "User Environment Variables" level, for all shells to inherit from it.