# Make Github SSH available to console in Windows 7

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have windows 7. I have setup GitHub for windows with SSH.

If I open Github for windows, and open a "git" console - I can see my project. I can SSH into github:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
"Hi! You've successfully authenticated"
```

But if I access git via my normal command line:

```
git --version
"git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1"
```

I can not use SSH:

```
git clone git@github.com:MyGitHubUserName/test.git
"Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository"
```

So how do I make a SSH key for my main "console" - rather than just the "git bash" console?

Comment: This looks like your environment variables are different for your standard environment.  You will want to probably read this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6612923/485864).